# Why split not working correctly?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Dim strVal="Male, Female"
Dim ArrCon = strVal.Split(" , ")
```

Result:  `ArrCon.Length` is `2`.

Which means the string got split, where it should be not split.

I only want split this text that have space before and after `,` eg: `Male , Female`.

Why `Split` not working correctly?

Comment: I only want split this text :"Male , Female". not want split text "Male, Female"

Comment: [Male,] and [Female]

Comment: Question is unclear. Why you expect that split returns an array which length is not 2? What do you expect instead?

Comment: the example is correct, he is asking why is that "male, female" got split using `strVal.Split(" , ")` where it should be not split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Result:  ArrCon.Length is 2.

It's not clear what you exptect. But i give it a try.

The problem is that you have `Option Strict Off`. Otherwise your code would not even compile because [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) has no overload that takes only a `string`. What happens if you have set it to `Off`(never!) is that only the first char of the string is taken and used as split-delimiter, so the empty space. It's the same as using: `strVal.Split(" "c)` or `strVal.Split()`.

Instead you want this:

```
Dim ArrCon = strVal.Split({" , "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Now the whole string is used, so the result is an array with length=1 which seems to be expected. The string doesn't contain the split-delimiter, so the array contains only the whole input string.